# How To Add Items In A Multi-Dimensional Jagged Array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I am trying to add items to an already existing jagged array and I am having some trouble. My program is a console application that is used to deal with student grades (adding students, deleting students, changing names, adding grades to various students, etc). I am reading in a sequential file that contains student ID, name, and then the grades (0-100) for each student. I decided to use a jagged array because I don't know how many grades each student will have, nor do I know how many students I will have.

Right now I am trying to add grades to existing students. My text file looks like this:

```
 00000,Mimzi Dagger,100,50,75,70,45,10,98,83
 00001,Alexander Druaga,89,45,80,90,15,73,99,100,61
 00002,Nicholas Zarcoffsky,100,50,80,50,75,100,100
 00003,Kantmiss Evershot,50,100
```

I want to be able to use a For loop and search for the student ID that the user enters, once I find that student ID I want to add a grade under that student. Here is a piece of my code, but it doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (studentID == studentArray[i][0])
    {
        studentArray[i][studentArray[i].Length + 1] = newGrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the type of `studentArray` `object[]`?

Comment: Can you also show the code that creates each `newGrade` from the sequential files?

Comment: Definitely use an ArrayList of student class instances containing an id and an ArrayList of integer grades. C# gives you this stuff out of the box why not use it, ArrayLists can grow as needed.

Comment: @Enigmativity studentArray is originally called fileArray. It's a string[][] array. I entered the grades in the original text file verses entering them in the program. I wanted to have some students and grades already in the text file.

Comment: @user2732617 I can't use a student class for this program. I can only have 1 control class. Will an ArrayList allow differing amounts of grades for each student?

Comment: Yes, look it up in the documentation on-line. Couldn't you have student as a nested class in the same file?

Comment: @user2732617 Nope, my program specifications are that I can only use 1 class. This is for a college course, so I can't exactly do it my own way.

Comment: See [`Array.Resize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand how to increase the size of the array so you can add a new value. Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, for a wealth of information including an explanation for why writing "it doesn't work" is insufficient. Finally note that for classroom assignments, you are generally _much_ better served asking your teacher, including: no chance of cheating (yourself and your grade); teacher knows what you need to learn; gives teacher feedback on what student areas need work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is something that I would never, ever do in the real world... I think it does satisfy your constraints for the assignment.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<List<string>> dataList = new List<List<string>>();

        dataList.Add(new List<string> { "00000", "Mimzi Dagger", "100", "50", "75", "70", "45",    "10", "98", "83" });
        dataList.Add(new List<string> { "00001", "Alexander Druaga", "89", "45", "80", "90", "15", "73", "99", "100", "61" });
        dataList.Add(new List<string> { "00002", "Nicholas Zarcoffsky", "100", "50", "80", "50", "75", "100", "100" });
        dataList.Add(new List<string> { "00003", "Kantmiss Evershot", "50", "100" });

        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var item in dataList[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, the output is: 00000
Mimi Dagger
100
50
75
70
45
10
98
83

00001
Alexander Druaga
89
45
80
90
15
73
99
100
61

00002
Nicholas Zarcoffsky
100
50
80
50
75
100
100

00003
Kantmiss Evershot
50
100

Comment: This is using a List though, not a jagged array?

Comment: Yes, I would normally use arrays when I know the finite number of elements. If you don't know the ultimate number of elements in your array and need to be able to enter more items occasionally I think it would be better to just use a List.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the most basic way of doing what you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (studentID == studentArray[i][0])
    {
        Array.Resize(ref studentArray[i], studentArray[i].Length + 1);
        studentArray[i][studentArray[i].Length - 1] = newGrade;
    }
}
```

Personally I find that a bit of a brain pain.

I'd rather write it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (studentID == studentArray[i][0])
    {
        studentArray[i] =
            studentArray[i]
                .Concat(new [] { newGrade })
                .ToArray();
    }
}
```